# How can I include the contents of a file as an argument to a macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to implement a Lisp version of [Processing](https://processing.org/), and to that end I'm employing the [`macro_lisp`](https://crates.io/crates/macro_lisp) crate to turn Lisp code into Rust at compile time.

It works when I structure my code like so:

**main.rs**

```
fn main() {
    include!("hello.lisp");
}
```

**hello.lisp**

```lisp
lisp!(println "hello")
```

Note that I have to wrap the content of `hello.lisp` in `lisp!()`, in `hello.lisp` itself.

I want it to be structured like so:

**main.rs**

```
fn main() {
    lisp!(include!("hello.lisp"));
}
```

**hello.lisp**

```
println "hello"
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
error: expected expression, found `<eof>`
  --> src/main.rs:47:18
   |
47 |     lisp!(include!("draw.lisp"));
   |                  ^ expected expression
```

There should not be an EOF there, there should be `hello "list"`.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to patch `macro_lisp`?

Comment: You want `lisp!(include_str!("hello.lisp"));`, not `include!`

Comment: @Shepmaster That unfortunately produces the same error! `lisp!(...)`s calling convention looks like `lisp!(println "{}" 12)`, it does not take a string.

Comment: Did you have success @Willem , how did you manage?

Comment: @Rainb, no. I managed by dropping Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this question is now 4 years old, I am the author of a crate that solves this exact issue in a maintainable way, and I'd like to save others the effort of re-implementing the required boilerplate by sharing how this would be solved using the [CPS](https://crates.io/crates/cps) crate.

Lukas' answer highlights that Rust requires some project-external code, like a build script or proc-macro, to implement inside-out macro evaluation. CPS is a crate that does the required proc-macro stuff for you, and introduces `let` bindings that allow you to write your desired `lisp!` macro as a macro-by-example:

```
#[cps::cps]
macro_rules! lisp_include {
    ($source:literal) => 
    let $($lisp_source:tt)* = cps::include!($source) in
    {
        lisp!($($lisp_source)*)
    }
}
```

After which you can use this extended version of the `lisp!` macro elsewhere in your code:

```
lisp_include!("hello.lisp");
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for at the time. I have to stand by my observation that hygienic macros in the way that they are implemented in Rust, tip the scales against Rust (in favor of either a C implementation or a Lisp) in the semantic reliability department; having realized this I don't benefit from a surface-level patch such as the `cps` crate, but it should still clarify the way the Rust macro system works so that is good for Rust programmers. ("Fighting the compiler" should really be counted as bugs in the language; programmer time is worth more than "idealistic" language.)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, what you want is not easy to achieve.

Macros work significantly different than functions. The important part for this question is that **"nested macro calls" are evaluated from "outside to inside"** (unlike functions, where arguments are evaluated first, so "inside to outside"). We can see that in effect with this tiny program:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ($x:literal) => { "literal" };
    ($x:ident ! ()) => { "ident ! ()" };
}

macro_rules! bar {
    () => { 3 };
}

fn main() {
    let s = foo!(bar!());
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

As you can see [on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f1fdc789becdf1b3086561833e0dfec9), it prints `ident ! ()`. That means the `bar!()` macro was not evaluated before `foo!` was evaluated. (Furthermore, the compiler even warns about the unused macro definition `bar`.)

`include!` is no exception to this, so we can't use it as an argument to other macros. So how *can* you do it? I can think of two ways, neither of which is particularly easy or elegant:

- Write a procedural macro that loads the file and emits the token stream `lisp! { ... }` where `...` is the file content. It could be tricky to get all the paths right (and to make sure everything is correctly recompiled when the lisp file changes), but it should in theory work.
- Use a build script to manually replace `include!("*.lisp")` strings in your source code with the file content. Obviously, you don't actually want to modify your real source code (that is checked into git), but have to be a bit clever about it. A few crates use such a tactic, but only for very special reasons. I wouldn't advise to do this in your case.

In your case, I would think twice whether using a lot of LISP code in Rust is a good idea, because there aren't any nice ways to make it work (as far as I can see).